# Placing buttons in a specified location using swing in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to learn how to make JAVA programs and I am working with Swing. I am trying to place a button in the top left corner of the window and it keeps going to the top center.

```
public void createGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Project");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setSize(400, 350);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel);

    addButtonGUI(panel, new JButton(), "test", 1, 1);
}

public void addButtonGUI(JPanel panel, JButton button, String text, int x, int y){
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    button.setText(text);
    button.setEnabled(true);
    gbc.gridx = x;
    gbc.gridy = y;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.weightx = 1.0D;
    gbc.fill = 2;
    panel.add(button, gbc);
}
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?
Please help

Comment: `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);`  Don't use magic numbers.  The J2SE has descriptively named constants for these values.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the layout of the `JPanel` to `GridBagLayout` to use `GridBagConstraints`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

Also as you only have one effective 'cell' you need to use an anchor and set `weighty` for the `JButton` to allow movement in the Y-axis.

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```

Also I would set the `fill` setting to `NONE`:

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
```

so that the button does not occupy the full width of the panel. (2 = *HORIZONTAL* fill).

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
addButtonGUI(panel, new JButton(), "test", 1, 1);
}
```

what would happen if you used

```
addButtonGUI(panel, new JButton(), "test", 0, 0);
}
```